# Extending Panels default layouts

Tags: panels, theming

I'm making my first steps into Panels (yeah, shame on me I waited so long)... I immediately ran into a problem with the column-resize widget which did not want to obey. So I thought maybe there i a programmatic workaround for my need.

What I need is a 5-row layout:

```
1: 1 column
2: 3 equal columns
3: 1 column
4: 2 columns (2:1 ratio)
5: 1 column
```

How do I add a custom layout (with own icon, name and php template) so that Panels recognizes it?

Comment: Is this way (using heredoc) a proper one?: http://2bits.com/articles/panels-how-to-create-your-own-custom-panel.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Here I found the [answer](http://drupal.org/project/panels_extra_layouts)